# In what order is meshgrid defined in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990127/plotting-a-3d-heat-map-in-matplotlib) and have almost figured out the answer by myself.
The only thing that remains is the following:
I am using `meshgrid` to create a 3D grid. When specifying the colors in `color_map.set_array(colo)` I am using an array which has the same size as elements in the `meshgrid`. But how does this array have to be ordered to yield the correct plot?

```
x=[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

y=  [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

z= [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]

colo=np.random.normal(0, 1, 216)

X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

color_map = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.Greens_r)
color_map.set_array(colo)

img = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, marker='s',
                 s=200, color='green')
plt.colorbar(color_map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the lengths of `y`, `x` and `z` are 6, 5, and 4 (I'm giving each axis a unique length in order to easily distinguish between them). The size of each meshgrid (`X`, `Y`, and `Z`) from `np.meshgrid(x, y, z)` will be 6x5x4. That means your data needs to be structured in the format `(y, x, z)`. Otherwise, the data won't line up with the arrangement of the meshgrid. You don't need to flatten the data.

If the data isn't in the format of `(y, x, z)`, rearrange it into that format. Then, you can give it to the colour parameter (`c=`) in `ax.scatter` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

#Make some test data
y = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
x = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
z = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
#Original data needs to be structured as (y, x, z)
original_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 120).reshape((6, 5, 4))

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y ,z)

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10)).add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

img = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, marker='s', s=200, c=original_data, cmap=cm.Greens_r)
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')
plt.colorbar(img)
```

[image]

Comment: it is a little weird though that it is ordered in this way.

Comment: It arises out of the format for `numpy` matrices `(row index, column index, 'depth' index)`. Which is equivalent to `(y axis, x axis, z axis)`.